# Why is regression line represented as $y = b0 + b1 * x$?

Tags: regression, linear, sums-of-squares

I am new to Data Science and ran into Regression Line formula which is

$ y = b0 + b1 *x $ (where x is dependent variable, y is predicted variable)

I understood the meaning of this formula as a linear graph. However, I did not get this part:

$b1 = \frac{\sum (x*y - \bar x*\bar y)}{\sum (x^2 - \bar x^2)}$

How can $b1$ be calculated like so?

Comment: I think you need to spend some time on the basic statistical knowledge. For example, definition of dependent variable and independent variables in the regression. The answer to your question can be found on the internet, for example: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/250/.

Comment: Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+formula+slope+derivation .